# What's wrong with how I'm using def in Python

Tags: python

Trying to use a function to change a from 0 to 1, but this outputs 0:

```
a = 0

def function():
    a = 1

function()

print (a)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong, you just need to declare `a` as a global variable in the function.

Comment: `a` is local to the function when you assign it. `global` is the keyword you are looking for here, but in most cases, if the answer is `global`, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: define function as `def function(a):` and call it as `function(a)`